# How to Save or Print or Download charts/files from Excel Task pane?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

Tried using:

**Highchart/Export.JS**: On implementing export/download as pdf/png in excel browser, opens chart in popup window but can not download.

**Fusion Chart**: No response in excel browser on click of print chart /Download PNG

**FileSaver JS**: Plugin works for charts created using  but gives error on click of download link(like canvas.toBlob is undefined)

**API to download Excel sheet**: Server gives proper response but no file downloaded to Downloads folder

-->Currently using window.open() to download data by creating a blank page in HTML which will only execute the download functionality.But saving the chart as pdf/print is still NOT WORKING.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the scenario. Are you looking to print a chart you created in your taskpane or print a chart that was inserted into Excel?

Comment: I am trying to print the chart created from task pane.

Answer (score 0):

You best bet would be to use the [Excel functions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) from Microsoft Graph API.  This API supports fetching a chart image.